# Change point detection in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where one column contains the following elements:

```
[2,2.5,3,2,2.6,10,10.3,10,10.1,10.3,10],
```

is there a python function that can detect the sudden change from 2.6 to 10 from that list? I have read a little bit and [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/changepoint/changepoint.pdf) can do that. Is there a similar function in python?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what are you expecting to get and why? Why not from 2 to 2.6 for example?

Answer (score 11):

IIUC you  could use [`pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) for that to find differencies between neighbours and then compare with your limit (whatever it'll be):

```
s = pd.Series([2,2.5,3,2,2.6,10,10.3,10,10.1,10.3,10])

In [105]: s.pct_change()
Out[105]:
0          NaN
1     0.250000
2     0.200000
3    -0.333333
4     0.300000
5     2.846154
6     0.030000
7    -0.029126
8     0.010000
9     0.019802
10   -0.029126
dtype: float64

In [107]: s[s.pct_change() > 1]
Out[107]:
5    10
dtype: float64

In [117]: s[s.pct_change() > 1].index.tolist()
Out[117]: [5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample signal is very simple. As answered above, a lag-1 (1st-order) differencing suffices to give you a spike that can be located as the changepoint. If the signal is more complex, some model-based approaches may be helpful. In Python, the `ruptures` package is definitely an excellent choice. If a Bayesian method is needed, one choice is the `Rbeast` package I developed (https://pypi.org/project/Rbeast).